# Anti-hack system : Reduce Server Overhead and Prevent OCR

Tags: node.js, cryptography, socket.io, ocr

Note : I've been down voted because the post was too vague. I've provided extensive information on research below. Scroll down the answer to see the precise problem.

I am writing a real-time multiplayer card game. All the logic of the game is on the server. Though, I am worried about hackers being able to exploit the game. I would like a very **strong protection**, as I would like it to be a paying tournament game at one point.

### A little intro

It's a turn-based game. The goal is to get all the cards. Each player has a pack of cards that they don't see. Turn by turn, they reveal a card by putting it on the center of the board. One of the rules is that if two cards of the same kind (A-A, K-K, 9-9) appear, anyone can tap, and the first one to tap wins the pack.

### How it works

The client receives socket.io "card" events. The event data contains the card kind, card rank, and the id of the player that discarded it.

`event : {rank : "Ace", kind : "Spades", playerId : 3}`.

When the client receives that, Phaser will load the corresponding sprite image and display it on the board.

Maybe you see the problem. For a hacker, identifying two consecutive events where the rank would be the same would be easy, e.g.:

`{rank : "Ace", kind : "Spades", playerId : 3}`

`{rank : "Ace", kind : "Hearts", playerId : 4}`

See "Ace", "Ace"? That would be too easy to identify.

### Strategy #1 : Encryption of sprites

Then, I thought maybe I would encrypt the "sprites" themselves, and send, along with the "card" event, the key and the filename to decrypt. The "card" event now would look like :

```
{sprite : "randomFileName", key : "aSecretKey", player : 3}
```

But again, I realized, once the files were decrypted, it would be almost as easy. After a little while in the game, all the cards would have appeared at least once, allowing the hacker to associate every sprite file with the corresponding rank. e.g:

```
randomFileName1 -> King
randomFileName2 -> Ace
randomFileName3 -> Jack
```

### Strategy #2 : Renewal of sprites

To prevent this, I thought, once a player would decrypt a card, he would not be able to identify it again because his client would download a couple of new encrypted sprites. The `renewalRate` would be the number of cards downloaded from the server after one was used.

e.g:

**Sprites on the client side**

```
// These are the sprites files on the client side.
// User doesn't know yet what they are 
// ? : means the user doesn't know what it is
// (): contains the id of the card
Sprites : 

   randomFileName1 -> ?  (King)
   randomFileName2 -> ?  (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ?  (Jack)
```

**Client receives an event**

```
// An event from the server
Event : 

   {
       fileName : "randomFileName2"

     , key : "randomFileName2Key"

     , playerId : 3

     // The number of files to renew would be equal to the "renewalRate" variable
     // The higher the renewalRate, the less chance the user can identify
     // a resource after it was re-downloaded.
     , renew : [randomFileName1, randomFileName2] 
   }
```

**User can now identify the Ace**

```
// User can identify randomFileName2 as an Ace because he could decrypt it
// And display it
Sprites : 

   randomFileName1 -> ?   (King)
   randomFileName2 -> Ace (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ?   (Jack)
```

**User renews the Ace file and some other files to mix it up**

```
// User renews files randomFileName1 and randomFileName2 
// as specified in the event.
//
// This way, he doesn't know no more which of the new file is the "Ace"
// Ace has 50% chance of being randomFileName4 or randomFileName5
// In general, a card has 1/(renewalRate) chance of 
// being identified after renewal. 
//
// In this case, renewalRate = 2.
// So chances to identify the Ace is (½ = 50%) among randomFileName4 and 5
Download

 x randomFileName1 -> ?   (King)
 x randomFileName2 -> Ace (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ?   (Jack)
 + randomFileName4 -> ?   (Ace)  -> the consumed ace is redownloaded here
 + randomFileName5 -> ?   (King) -> Another card is renewed
```

**Sprites on the Client side**

```
Sprites : 

   randomFileName3 -> ?           (Jack)
   randomFileName4 -> ? (Ace 50%) (Ace)
   randomFileName5 -> ? (Ace 50%) (King)
```

### Strategy #3 : Delayed renewal of sprites

To circumvent this, I thought I could renew the cards in a deferred way, meaning that the re-downloaded cards would not for sure contain the previously used card. This would require the client to download multiple versions of the same card :

** Sprites on the Client side **

```
   randomFileName1 -> ? (King)
   randomFileName2 -> ? (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ? (Jack)
```

**Event**

```
Event : 

   {
       fileName : "randomFileName2"

     , key : "randomFileName2Key"

     , playerId : 3

     , renew : [randomFileName1, randomFileName2] 
   }
```

**Sprites on the Client side**

```
   randomFileName1 -> ?   (King)
   randomFileName2 -> Ace (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ?   (Jack)
```

**User download new sprites**

When the user downloads the new sprites, the consumed card (the Ace) is not necessarily contained in the new sprites. It might be downloaded the next time, or the second-next time a user consumes a card.

```
Download

 x randomFileName1 -> ?   (King)
 x randomFileName2 -> Ace (Ace)
   randomFileName3 -> ?   (Jack)
 + randomFileName4 -> ?   (3)
 + randomFileName5 -> ?   (9)
```

**Next turn**

```
Download

 x randomFileName3 -> ?   (Jack)
 x randomFileName4 -> 3   (3)
   randomFileName5 -> ?   (9)
 + randomFileName6 -> ?   (Ace) //Ace is re-downloaded now
 + randomFileName7 -> ?   (10)
```

### The problem

**Server overhead**

A card sprite : 5-10kB
Number of cards renewed by move : 3
Cards consumed / second in a game : 2
Number of games : 30
Total : 900kB/s - 1,800kB/s

Lots of server overhead. 1,800kB/s might be a little heavy. And there's just 30 games running.

**OCR**

Also, with this system, even if a player cannot identify a card by it's filename, once he receives the key, he might run an OCR to identify the card rank, and win too.

### My question

Are there encryption strategies, or other strategies, that could allow me to reduce the server overhead in this case, and to prevent a user from running an OCR on the image?

Comment: "I would like a very strong protection," - did SSL go out of fashion?

Comment: I don't understand why a hacker could cheat with the first solution ? Because he could tap before the sprite are loaded by sniffing the socket.io event ?

Comment: Basically yes. The cards appear multiple times during a game. Once a sprite was decrypted, he'll just have to sniff the socket.io event for that filename. If two socket.io successive socket.io events are received for two sprites he already decrypted, he'll know if he can tap or not.

Comment: To propose an analogy. Someone has 10 locked doors in front of him. He cannot open any of these doors. When he receives a key, he can open one. Receiving another key will let him open another door. If he can remember perfectly what all the keys he received looked like, and what door they opened, once he received a key, he'll know what door it opens. In this case, if a player receives a key to decrypt a sprite, once he decrypted it, any time he'll receive the same key will mean that the same card was discarded.

Answer (score 0):

A light way and not too complicated would be to have a way to encrypt the data and change the way to encrypt the data often. Could use the current time+20 seconds as a secret for the hash. Or some data in the application that would be sync between client and server. A moving variable that server and client could use together during the hash of the filename so that the hash is the same between client and server but the hash will be different 2 minutes after for the same name of card.
Time may not be the best choice but it's an example to get the global idea.

This way the encrypt name of your sprite would change everytime.

Not sure if i made my point clear.

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(filename+"(-)="+currentTime+20).digest('hex');
```

You send this hash, then with the client, for every filename, you hash and test with the hash received, so that you can find the good sprite to load.

Comment: If I send the user the key to encrypt his own filename, I'm sure he'll be able to track it. This does not solve the problem, unless I am misunderstanding your proposal.

Comment: Ok I think I understood. The problem is once the user knows which filename to load, he'll know the identity of that card. I want to mitigate the relationship filename->card.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something this is a game based on the normal deck of cards.

Why isn't the entire deck downloaded as images by the client up front (can be cached server side as well), and only meta data (text/json/xml representation of which card, etc) is being send back to the client in the requests/responses.  Dealing with literal card images being sent back and forth is not an issue that way, and you can focus on securing the data.

In terms of preventing players from cheating, do not make this stateless server side.  Manage the entire game server side, and just process requests from user actions/events.  There you can vet the action is valid, and the order in which they were received.

Let's say a player changes the data in the request (easy enough to do), well you know what cards they really have, and what cards are in play, so you acn easily mitigate that.

To prevent other players from seeing other peoples cards, use SSL.

Comment: The server manages the whole game, as stated. The reason why sprites would be downloaded again and again by the client, and be encrypted, would be to mitigate the identity of the sprites on the cline side. I don't want a user to know that "afwie2di29d.encrypted.jpeg" is an Ace of Spades. If he knows that, and if he knows the identity of every card, he could write a triggerbot who would just tap every time two cards of the same rank appeared. What I'm suggesting, is encrypting all the cards with a different key, send the key when needed, and renew the cards once the key has been used.

Comment: The only thing the client receives is a notification of a new card on the central pack, and the only thing he emits is a notification of tapping on the central pack or of discarding a card on it (a card he will not see until the server responds with the identity of the card). The client never sees his cards, nor the cards of others, until the server sends him a notification along with the id of the card to display.

Comment: Know up front that obfuscating the file names will cost you $$, as you lose caching client side.

Request #1: generate a UUID server side for each filename, and send that back as the card.
Request #2: Client does an image get via that UUID (You can cycle this as often as needed, and don't use a UUID for Ace, use a UUID for a particular Ace in the deck.)

For OCR, frankly it is not worth it.  If somebody can do OCR well enough, then it's no different than a real user looking at the screen, and protecting form it that will only impact the 99% of users who are not cheating.